# Sum objects together to create 1 object with all properties summed

Tags: c#

First of all, sorry about the title gore. I'm going to jump straight in with an example, as I'm not great at explaining.

I have a class:

```
public class Attributes
{
  public int HealthPoint { get; set; }

  public int Speed { get; set; }

  public static Attributes operator +(Attributes a, Attributes b)
  {
    return new Attributes()
    {
      HealthPoint = a.HealthPoint + b.HealthPoint,
      Speed = a.Speed + b.Speed,
    };
  }

  public static Attributes operator -(Attributes a, Attributes b)
  {
    return new Attributes()
    {
      HealthPoint = a.HealthPoint - b.HealthPoint,
      Speed = a.Speed - b.Speed,
    };
  }
}
```

As you can already tell, I've overloaded the operators so I can do the below:

```
var attributesC = attributesA + attributesB;
```

But I would much prefer to do the below:

```
var attributes = allAttributes.Sum();
```

I could use the below method:

```
public static Attributes Sum(this List<Attributes> attributes)
{
  var finalAttributes = new Attributes();

  foreach (var attribute in attributes)      
    finalAttributes += attribute;

  return finalAttributes;
}
```

But I was just hoping I could override/overload something instead.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `List<T>` is not `T`. You have to use extension method if you want to use syntax `List<T>.Method()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8) Linq method, which you are after, only works on pre-defined number types. It doesn't know how to handle your custom object (there is no "true generic" option, it doesn't have an overload to take any data type "that can be added to itself").

In this particular situation it would make sense to make your own extension method to do the summing operation. What you've got for code will work.

Side notes:

- You might want to change the argument from `List<Attributes>` to `IEnumerable<Attributes>` - it's more broad and allows you to pass in Lists, Arrays, or other IEnumerables (such as those filtered/ordered/etc through Linq).
- See if you can find a better name for the class. *Usually* class names that are plural are discouraged because they are an internal *collection* (similar to List). Of course, this particular one is tricky.

Comment: I figured this would be the response. But doesn't hurting trying. I'll make the amend to the argument, and have a look at changing my class name. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Yeah sorry. I wish there was an option for `Sum()` that allowed you to use generic types that had defined operators.